# Create String from CSV Lookup with AppleScript

Tags: csv, applescript

I am trying to create an applescript that will create a string out of a CSV file. It is very easy to create the string of the entire file, but I'd like to be able to scan the file for a certain organization. Below is my input and desired output.

**My CSV:**

```
Org1    Bobby Bob   bobbybob@gmail.com
Org1    Wendy Wen   wendywen@gmail.com
Org1    Rachel Rach rachelrach@gmail.com
Org2    Timmy Tim   ttim@otheremail.com
Org2    Ronny Ron   rron@otheremail.com
Org2    Mike Mik    mmik@otheremail.com
```

**My AppleScript:**

```
set csv to read csv_input_file as «class utf8»
set text item delimiters to ","
set csvParagraphs to paragraphs of csv

repeat with current_line in paragraphs of csv
    set organization to text item 1 of current_line

    --THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    set others_in_organization to ...

end repeat
```

**Desired Output:**

I would like to create a new string that contains a comma separated list of all of the other people in the current organization. For example, the fourth entry's organization is "Org2". So the string would return "Timmy Tim, Ronny Ron, Mike Mik".

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
set myOrg to "Org1"
set otherPeople to ""

set csv to "Org1,Bobby Bob,bobbybob@gmail.com
Org1,Wendy Wen,wendywen@gmail.com
Org1,Rachel Rach,rachelrach@gmail.com
Org2,Timmy Tim,ttim@otheremail.com
Org2,Ronny Ron,rron@otheremail.com
Org2,Mike Mik,mmik@otheremail.com"

set text item delimiters to ","
repeat with aLine in paragraphs of csv
    set textItems to text items of aLine
    if item 1 of textItems is not myOrg then
        set otherPeople to otherPeople & item 2 of textItems & ", "
    end if
end repeat
set text item delimiters to ""

if otherPeople ends with ", " then
    set otherPeople to text 1 thru -3 of otherPeople
end if
return otherPeople
```